# As a Terran player, what should I do differently as a result of the 1.4 patch gameplay changes?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

1.4 includes quite a few changes to gameplay (here is a condensed list):

- Unit vision up ramps has been reduced by 1.
- Immortal Attack range increased from 5 to 6.
- Mothership Acceleration increased from 0.3 to 1.375.
- Mothership's Cloaking Field no longer cloaks all units instantaneously, but rather adds units to the cloak field over time (maximum of 25 per second).
- Stalker Blink research time increased from 110 to 140.
- Warp Prism Shields increased from 40 to 100.
- Barracks Build time increased from 60 to 65.
- Hellion Infernal Pre-Igniter damage upgrade decreased from 10 to 5.
- Raven Seeker missile movement speed increased from 2.5 to 2.953.
- Infestor Fungal Growth damage changed from 36 (+30% armored) to 30 (40 vs Armored).
- Neural Parasite range decreased from 9 to 7.
- Overseer Morph cost decreased from 50/100 to 50/50.
- Contaminate energy cost increased from 75 to 125.
- Ultralisk Build time decreased from 70 to 55.

As a Terran player, what changes to my tactics and strategy should I be thinking about implementing as a result of these changes? For example, are there things that were uncommon or ineffective that I should now add to my play? Are there things that used to be common that I should now avoid?

Comment: These two questions, "As a Terran player, what changes to my tactics and strategy should I be thinking about implementing as a result of these changes? For example, are there things that were uncommon or ineffective that I should now add to my play?" Are really broad without telling us what your play style is or what strategies you implement on other races.

Comment: @Sorean, I agree, they are broad, I wanted to ask an intentionally broad question so that it would be useful to other players. I'm not looking for specifics like "you should build something else at 2:45 instead of what you are building now", but instead things like "Watch out for early ultralisks, and build lots of tanks to defend" or "Seeker missles are really useful now". I have no idea about these things, and I really don't play enough to figure them out on my own via trial and error (I only get to play about 2 hours a week). Also, my play style could generally be summed up as "more guys".

Comment: Okay, I'll try to expand my current answer then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll address each point from a Terran perspective.

**Unit vision up ramps has been reduced by 1.**

- This particular change is intended to hold off protoss 4 gate attack effectiveness. As a Terran it won't affect you much if you have flying units/buildings.

**Immortal Attack range increased from 5 to 6.**

- This change will make your siege tanks die much faster during battles with protoss armies (assuming they micro the immortals correctly). You may want to ensure that you target these in a skirmish to ensure your tanks stay alive longer.

**Mothership Acceleration increased from 0.3 to 1.375.**

- Given how little this unit is used, it shouldn't really affect terran play much. All it means is that the mothership can move faster. If you have the right army composition the mothership will still die just as fast, regardless of its movement speed.

**Mothership's Cloaking Field no longer cloaks all units instantaneously, but rather adds units to the cloak field over time (maximum of 25 per second).**

- This change was to help computers not have a lag spike when the unit entered the field. Because when it entered it cloaked everything causing the system to have a suddenly heavy load on the system. This in turn sort of gave opponents a slight edge, if they noticed the skip late game they knew a mothership was out without scouting. This change really doesn't affect the Terran race at all, just more of a system handling thing.

**Stalker Blink research time increased from 110 to 140.**

- From a Terran perspective it simply means that this tech will be out slower than before and that you can adjust your play appropriately for that kind of timing push/tactic.

**Warp Prism Shields increased from 40 to 100.**

- This means it will be a lot harder to kill warp prisms. It's already been noticed that since the patch there are a lot more protoss players making warp prisms and incorporating them into play. In regards to Terran, you're going to have to be on the lookout for a lot more drop/warp-in type play from protoss players.

**Barracks Build time increased from 60 to 65.**

- This change will affect early terran build timings a lot. An extra 5 seconds on the barracks will throw off the timing of your early SCV production and Orbital Command build times. People are still playing with this timing now.

**Hellion Infernal Pre-Igniter damage upgrade decreased from 10 to 5.**

- This change was made to lower the effectiveness of the hellion upgrade since blue flame play was dominating TvT play and completely changed the landscape of TvT battles at the high level. Granted the units are still good with the upgrade, you just have to make a few more of them and make more use with them early on.

**Raven Seeker missile movement speed increased from 2.5 to 2.953.**

- The missle moves faster which means it can catch some slower moving units making it difficult to micro away the unit the missle is chasing. As a terran this is definitely a buff to the ability.

**Infestor Fungal Growth damage changed from 36 (+30% armored) to 30 (40 vs Armored).**

- This change meant that banelings can survive 1 fungal growth, it was more a change for ZvZ fights than a fight with Terran. However, this lower damage does mean that your medivacs have more time to respond in a marine heavy army. Also does mean that your Armored units (Maruaders, tanks, etc) take slightly less damage as well.

**Neural Parasite range decreased from 9 to 7.**

- This was called a huge nerf by the zerg community. As a terran with seige tanks in play you'll be less likely to see this kind of play as their infestors have to move that much closer to your units to take control of them. And with any kind of supporting units around, the infestors can die really quickly. Infestors are more likely just to be used for fungal growths versus a terran army now.

**Overseer Morph cost decreased from 50/100 to 50/50.**

- Cheaper early mobile detection for zerg. More of a balance change for zerg because their units cost a lot of gas (but that's pretty true for all races, except marine heavy play), but might also factor into the the next change causing a new style of play to emerge.

**Contaminate energy cost increased from 75 to 125.**

- This means you will see less contaminates on your buildings, for most leagues/divisions this ability isn't used much right now, but if it is used properly, it can be really devastating as you won't be able to produce any units from your buildings.

**Ultralisk Build time decreased from 70 to 55.**

- The actual timing of how long it takes to get to Ultralisk tech doesn't change at all, however getting them into the field faster to join the battle will. A bit of a buff to zerg players that are making a tech switch and trying to get that "surprise" factor on their opponents giving them less time to react. So as a terran, it means you have a lot less time to prepare for them if you scan and see the ultralisk cavern.